# Is it possible to remove background from image or making the background transparent using opencv in java. Input image must be in bitmap form

Tags: android

I am confronted with the issue to remove the background of object from image or making the background transparent. Object must be the human body and input image must be in bitmap form. I have gone through the multiple questions related to this issue but nothing is working for me.

Below is the code i am working with. But it is not rendering desired results. This code makes the image transparent inside the object too.

```
public Bitmap removeBackground(Bitmap bitmap) {
    //GrabCut part
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, imageMat);

    int r = imageMat.rows();
    int c = imageMat.cols();
    Point p1 = new Point(c / 100, r / 100);
    Point p2 = new Point(c - c / 100, r - r / 100);
    Rect rect = new Rect(p1, p2);

    Mat mask = new Mat();
    Mat fgdModel = new Mat();
    Mat bgdModel = new Mat();

    Mat imgC3 = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(imageMat, imgC3, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);

    Imgproc.grabCut(imgC3, mask, rect, bgdModel, fgdModel, 5, Imgproc.
            GC_INIT_WITH_RECT);

    Mat source = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(3.0));
    Core.compare(mask, source/* GC_PR_FGD */, mask, Core.CMP_EQ);

    //This is important. You must use Scalar(255,255, 255,255), not Scalar(255,255,255)
    Mat foreground = new Mat(imageMat.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(255,
            255, 255,255));
    imageMat.copyTo(foreground, mask);

    // convert matrix to output bitmap
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) foreground.size().width,
            (int) foreground.size().height,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(foreground, bitmap);
    return bitmap;
}
```

[this is actual image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVxlz.jpg)

> [output image should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c24ua.jpg)

Comment: could you maybe post a picture of what you want the result to look like. Don't exactly know what you mean with the "the code makes the image transparent in the object too"? Are you trying to make the "human body" image the colour of the input bitmap, but the rest of the human body image must be transparent? I believe there is a masking method you can use (maybe this: https://badoo.com/techblog/blog/2016/10/17/masking-bitmaps/ use PORTERDUFF to correctly mask an image)

Comment: I have edited my question. Now images are available to make problem more implicit.

Comment: Ok,will you have a mask image available (cause then the link above can help you) else if you want to do image processing, then you can look into using renderscript or better openCV code (cant help you there though :'( )